# how to match queries with apollo's refetchQuery

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-client

My fundimental question is do the variables for queries need to be exact for refetchQueries to work. Or can you give it a subset of variables and it will match similar queries.

Consider the following ....

```
  <Query<NotesQuery, NotesQueryVariables>
      query={notesQuery}
      variables={{
        input: {
          notebookId: notebookContext.id,
          first: 20
        }
      }}
    >
</Query>
```

and the following mutation:

```
    client
      .mutate<NoteCreateOrUpdateMutation, NoteCreateOrUpdateMutationVariables>({
        mutation: noteCreateOrUpdateMutation,
        variables: {
          input: {
            noteId: note ? note.id : undefined,
            subjectIds: noteSubjects,
            notebookId: notebookContext.id,
            authorId: userContext.id,
            content: noteContent,
            context: noteCaption,
          }
        },
        refetchQueries: [
          {
            query: notesQuery,
            variables: { input: { notebookId: notebookContext.id } } as NotesQueryVariables
          }
        ]
      })
```

when I do that mutation it is NOT refetching the note query with the pagination

If I add the `first: 20` parameter -- it works.

I would like it to clear all noteQueries that match with the given parameters.  Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you'll be wanting to add `@connection` directives to your `gql` definitions of `notesQuery` and `measurementsQuery`. You didn't post those, so unfortunately I can't show you exactly what that would look like for your use case.

Anyway, the `@connection` directive will allow Apollo to match on `notebookId` for example, while ignoring the value of `first`.

Unfortunately, you've bundled all your input into the object `input`, and I don't know how you would select just `notebookId` with the filter. Assuming that your `gql` definition looks something like this for `notesQuery`:

```
const notesQuery = gql`
  query notes($input: InputType!) {
    notes(input: $input) @connection(key: "notes", filter: ["input['notebookId']"]) {
      id
      ...
    }
  }
`;
```

^^^ Unfortunately, that won't work because of the way that `apollo-utilities/lib/storeUtils.js` -> `getStoreKeyName()` function works. It'll just ignore the above attempt to get better resolution than an arg name, i.e. can't go beyond `input`. Any string in the filter array that doesn't match an arg name is silently ignored.

Looks like you'll have to modify your schema.

More info at: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/features/pagination.html#connection-directive